# Telebot (pyTelegramBotAPI): how to wait for a single reply and stop the bot

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I'm trying to implement a function in Python that would just send a message via telegram bot, wait for a single reply, stop the bot and return the reply.

The following code works correctly, but only once: on the second call telebot receives the same reply. Tried reading the docs (especially about polling), but got more confused, actually...What would be a simple way to achieve my goal?

```
def get_answer(question: str) -> str:
    bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
    result = ''

    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda _: True)
    def handle_reply(message):
        nonlocal result
        result = message.text
        bot.stop_polling()

    bot.send_message(TELEGRAM_ID, question)
    bot.infinity_polling()

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `types.ForceReply(selective=False)` and check if the message user sent is replied to the message. Here is some code that may help:

```
from telebot import *
bot = TeleBot('TOKEN')
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda _: True)
def send_msg(message):
    msg_id = message.message_id
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Please, reply to this message!", reply_markup=types.ForceReply(selective=False))
    register_next_step_handler(msg, handle_reply)
def handle_message(message):
    try:
        if message.reply_to_message.message_id == msg_id:
            bot.send_message("You replied to the message and bot polling stopped")
            bot.stop_polling()
        else:
            bot.send_message("You replied to another message")
    except:
        bot.send_message("You did not replied to any message")
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Thanks! Firstly, ```handle_message``` has no access to ```msg_id```, and secondly, I don't see much difference with my snippet, i.e. I assume that bot will still get the previous message for some reason.